# Basic command problems

Tags: grep, find, sudo, exec, wc

I tried to figure out what is the difference those commands (for a school project), but for me its chrashed or running for more than 10min~

**So, the sample:**

> *sudo find / -type f -exec file ’{}’ ; | grep ’Shell script’ | wc -l*

**the differences:**

#without ' ' at {}

1. ```
   sudo find / -type f -exec file {} \; | grep ’Shell script’ | wc -l
   ```

#without the \

2. ```
   sudo find / -type f -exec file ’{}’ ; | grep ’Shell script’ | wc -l
   ```

#without ' ' after grep command

3. ```
   sudo find / -type f -exec file ’{}’ \; | grep Shell script | wc -l
   ```

***Thanks for your time, and help.***

Comment: First, you need to replace the typographic `’smart quotes’` with regular `'ASCII quotes'` - then have a read of these: [Special meaning of '{}' ';' with find](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/212384/special-meaning-of-with-find) and [GNU find and masking the {} for some shells - which?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/8647/gnu-find-and-masking-the-for-some-shells-which)

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you need to use straight quotes (`'`), not typographical ones, as noted by steeldriver.

Second, the effect of the presence of quotes or not makes a difference in what the command itself receives:

For example, you could have:

```bsh
echo 'semicolon ; echo message'
```

Here the command echo¹ is run with the parameter `semicolon ; echo message`. And thus the output would be a line saying

> semicolon ; echo message

Now suppose that there were no quotes:

```bsh
echo semicolon ; echo message
```

The program echo would function exactly in the same way (printing the parameter). However, the difference is that, since `;` is a special character for the shell, the shell itself would treat the line differently, as two commands:

- echo semicolon
- echo message

The output would be:

> semicolon
> message

There are three places on your lines that may be quoted or not:

- `{}`

As noted on [GNU find and masking the {} for some shells - which?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/8647/70346) *most* shells won't require quoting a standalone {}, and thus it won't make a difference.

- `;`

`find` requires a `;` to finish the single-argument `-exec`. As `;` is special for the shell, it needs to be quoted (as `\;`, `';'` or `";"`, it doesn't matter, just not as a literal `;`). Otherwise _the shell_would interpret it as a find command, then a second command starting with a pipe (`|`), which leads to a shell error:

> syntax error near unexpected token `|'

- `Shell script`

For the `grep` you have two very different outputs. In the first case, you call grep with a single argument (`Shell script`). In the other, it is called with two arguments (first `Shell`, second `script`). Given the  way grep works, in the first case it would look for lines received on its input that contain the text *Shell script*. In the second, it would look for lines containing the text *Shell* in a file named `script`. Which are quite different behaviors.

This information should let you figure out which would be the right line to run, and the reason to write it that way.

¹ Actually a shell builtin will be called, but let's assume it's the standalone `/bin/echo` the one that runs.

---

Finally, the correct line does three things.

- Run the command [`file`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/hirsute/en/man1/file.1.html) _on each and every file of your system`
- Select those lines (describing those files) that contain the text *Shell script*
- Count the number of lines (and thus of shell scripts)

(the last command would be equivalent to using `grep -c`)

As such, you won't receive the output of the command (which is a number) until after running a program thousands and thousands of times (one per entry in your filesystem), so *it's perfectly normal that it takes a long time to run*.

You can run it inside a folder skipping the `/` so it only searches that subtree.

Another way to see what it is doing would be to insert a `tee /dev/stderr` on the pipeline:

```bsh
find / -type f -exec file {} \; | tee /dev/stderr | grep "Shell script" | wc -l
```

Comment: @roaima Indeed. You could get the same effect with backslash escapes. I was referring on wheteher or not to have quotes there. I mentioned the equivalence later on `;`, although I didn't want to get into the difference of single and double quotes, nor in the more exotic quotings.